2,6,?,30,-270 number sequence
Got this number sequence puzzle from a friend. 

Reddit, I think.

I think the answer is

 -6

The rule is

 
 To generate the next number in the sequence. You multiply the previous number of the sequence by a number. That number is -4 less than the number you used to generate the previous number in the sequence. So we have 2 x 3, 6 x -1, -6 x -5 and 30 x -9!!!


Damn 10 upvotes thanks!
